# Как заменить только 6-й элемент строки

Tags: python, python-3.x

Есть строка:

```
s2 = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
ss = s2.replace(s2[6], "X")
print(ss)
```

И я хочу заменить на «Х» только 6-й элемент строки, а мне заменяет полностью строку на «ХХХХХХХХХХХХХХ»

Что делать?

Comment: `ss = s2[:6] + "X" + s2[7:]`

Comment: А как убрать стоящий после «Х» малый х, ведь если использовать функцию remove, то пропадут все х, так ведь?

Comment: Просто не используйте функцию, если она вам не подходит

Answer (score 3):

Ну например можно разобрать строку в список по отдельным буквам и делать с конкретными позициями что хотите:

```py
s2 = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
l2 = list(s2)
l2[6] = "X"
ss = ''.join(l2)
print(ss)
# xxxxxxXxxxxxxxx
```

Answer (score 3):

Ваш код делает совсем не то, что вам кажется он должен делать. Разберем предложение `s2.replace(s2[6], "X")` по составу:

`s2` равно `"xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"`, `s2[6]` равно `"x"`. Подставим в исходную строчку, получим

`"xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx".replace("x", "X")` - т.е. просим заменить в строке `"xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"` каждый символ `"x"` на `"X"`. Что и происходит.

Answer (score 2):

можно с помощью регулярки сделать замену:

```
from re import sub

s2 = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"

sub(r'^(.{5})(.)',r'\1X',s2)  # 'xxxxxXxxxxxxxxx'
```